# How to get all items from CosmosDB cross partition query in a single (or minimal) trips to the database?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to return multiple documents from several specific partitions in a single query, however I found that the query does extra database trip for each partition.

Here is the query that is being sent to cosmos db to get data from 3 partitions (`AltairCode` is PartitionKey):

```
select c.AltairCode, c.ReportedDate, c.UpdatedDate, c.TimesheetStatus, c.DurationValue, c.DurationPercentageValue from c 
where (not is_defined(c.IsDeleted) or c.IsDeleted = false) and 
((c.AltairCode = '10128003' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-12-01') or --returns 4 documents
(c.AltairCode = '10125130' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-11-01') or --returns 9 documents
(c.AltairCode = '10127661' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-06-01')) --returns 5 documents
```

Here is a .Net code that executes the query (I hardcoded this query for ease)

```
public async Task<CosmosResultsResponseMessage<T>> QueryItems<T>(string sql, List<(string name, object value)> parameters = null)
{
    var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_databaseName, _containerName);

    sql = "select c.AltairCode, c.ReportedDate, c.UpdatedDate, c.TimesheetStatus, c.DurationValue, c.DurationPercentageValue from c where (not is_defined(c.IsDeleted) or c.IsDeleted = false) and ((c.AltairCode = '10128003' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-12-01') or (c.AltairCode = '10125130' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-11-01') or (c.AltairCode = '10127661' and c.ReportedDate >= '2023-06-01'))";
    QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(sql);

    var allItems = new List<T>();
    var result = new CosmosResultsResponseMessage<T>();
    
    using (var streamResultSet = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(query))
    {
        while (streamResultSet.HasMoreResults)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await streamResultSet.ReadNextAsync())
            {
                result.IsSuccessStatusCode = responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                result.StatusCode = responseMessage.StatusCode;
                result.ErrorMessage = responseMessage.ErrorMessage;

                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var streamResponse = FromStream<dynamic>(responseMessage.Content);
                    List<T> items = streamResponse.Documents.ToObject<List<T>>();
                    allItems.AddRange(items);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result.ResultItems = allItems;
    return result;
}
```

I found that this code goes to the database **3** times instead of **1**, just to return **18** documents, with 3 database trips happening at `streamResultSet.ReadNextAsync()` line (And with `streamResultSet.HasMoreResults` returning `true` 3 times).

How can you force it to do a single trip to database?
Or perhaps there is another way to get data from several partitions in a single trip to the database?

Comment: What is the Partition Key Definition of the container? If you are not filtering in the query by the Partition Key, then you are doing a Cross Partition query. It's impossible to serve a Cross Partition query with a single network request if the container has multiple physical partitions.

Comment: I am not sure how to get Partition Key definition. In the Azure Portal UI it says "Non-hierarchically partitioned container" under Partition Key. I don't know whether container has multiple physical partitions, but I am surprised it is not possible to have a single network request for cross partition query. What is the best way to do a query like that in a minimal amount of database trips? It doesn't make much sense to me to have multiple database trips for such small amount of documents. Why can't they be all combined on the server side before being returned to me?

Answer (score 1):

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#direct-mode
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions

Physical partitions in Cosmos DB are independent sets of machines, each physical partition has a replica set that provides high availability.

From the connectivity point of view, because these are different machines, they have different endpoints.

It's not possible to do a single network request to multiple endpoints, this is not particular to Cosmos DB, but in general, if you need to connect to different endpoints, they need to be different requests.

In a Cross-Partition Query, by definition, the query needs to go to different Partitions. If it needs to go to different Partitions, then the only way is to make requests to each Partition, because each Partition has different endpoints.

If this were a Single-Partition Query, then it would be 1 connection, but even in that case, you might require more than 1 requests, it depends on the volume of data (not just documents) and it depends on the type of query and the RUs available. More details on https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination

So, simple answer, there is no way to guarantee that all the data of a query will always be returned in a single connection/network request. In some conditions it might (Single-Partition query, no RU throttles, response under 4Mb) but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the thorough answer, however even if there are 3 physical round trips to the 3 physical partitions to get data, why do those trips have to be carried over to the client?
Surely 3 internal round trips inside the data center are much faster than 3 external data trips for the client?
For me it takes 1-7 sec. per round trip (admittedly in debug mode), and this is just for small test queries. 
The whole reason for my query is to do a batch processing server side and to give me all the results in one go.
Surely there is a way to run these queries on the server or in parallel?

Comment: @Tanuki You normally do those queries concurrently and thus it's not three times your request time. The time for each result to return may also vary and running it client side allows you to start processing those without a server waiting for the other requests. I imagine that's especially relevant when specific partitions are at their throughput limits.

Comment: @Tanuki discussing how the backend system should or should not work or having an opinionated discussion about how the overall system should work from different points of view is out of scope of this area. I am describing how the system works and how the client libraries interact with it. This is not something the client libraries can change. If your question is if you can change how the backend system work, then that question is outside the scope of SO because it is no longer about programming but rather how a product should be designed.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Hmmm, I was trying to see if there is any way to achieve server side cross partition batch processing. Something that in my eyes should have been pretty trivial. Thank you again for explaining how the cross partition queries currently work, but it doesn't answer the question in the title. The answer to the question from what I understand (with these system limitations) is to create a Stored procedure that does querying per partition in parallel and then sends combined results back to the client. I will need to research if it possible and how to do it next.

Comment: The answer to the question is in my answer, and it's No. Stored Procedures cannot do cross-partition operations as the execution of a Stored Procedure is always scoped to a single Partition Key Value (not physical partition). Even then, you need to do 1 network request per partition, and if the execution takes more than 5 seconds, it is terminated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits